# How does EMGU CV convert an RGB image to grayscale?

Tags: image-processing, emgucv

I already know how to convert an image to grayscale using EMGU CV.

This is the example code:

```
Image<Gray, byte> sourceimage = new Image<Gray, byte>(Group[i]);
```

This function converts the image to grayscale.

I want to know what calculation EMGU CV uses to convert an RGB image to grayscale, like Red * A + Green * B + Blue * C = Gray intensity.

So what are A, B and C?

Comment: If it wraps OpenCV's `cvtColor` (which I think it does), you can [find the coefficients described here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

Comment: @Roger Rowland nicely done. Thank you